# How to compress build files in react app?

Tags: reactjs

I want to know How to compress the .js and .css files after a normal react build. Right now I am using this script

```
    "build": "npm run watch:css && react-scripts build",
    "postbuild": "cd ./build/static && gzip *.js && gzip *.css",
```

to compress the files but it's showing me this error message every time when I build the app using `npm run build`.

[image]

build folder structure:
[image]

Anyone, please help me with this.

Comment: better way is change webpack config or use the library like [craco](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@craco/craco)

Answer (score 3):

first: `npm i gzipper -g`

second: you can write these commands on package.json

```
"build": "react-scripts build && gzipper --verbose ./build"
```

then for compress, you need to use this :

```
"build":"react-scripts build && gzipper compress ./build"
```

if you want to zip CSS and js you can use :

```
"build": "react-scripts build && gzipper compress ./build/static/css && gzipper compress ./build/static/js",
```

it works for me very well :

[image]

Comment: right now I have this script to build the app. `    "build": "npm run watch:css && react-scripts build",`  Should I replace this with this `    "build": "npm run watch:css && react-scripts build && gzipper compress ./build/static/css && gzipper compress ./build/static/js",`

Comment: thanks for your answer and Is their any other method to improve the performance of the react app?

Comment: I usually use splitting my files

Comment: pay attention to the need to have a build. then you can compress it if there is not a build folder it means there is not a file to compress and you will get an error.

Comment: Is there any resource regarding splitting?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239199/discussion-between-samira-and-rishi-purwar).

Answer (score 2):

- Add **compress-create-react-app** `npm i compress-create-react-app`
- Edit script in `package.json`

```json
// package.json
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build && compress-cra", // <-- Edited
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

- Create `compress-cra.json` file on root folder

```json
// compress-cra.json
{
    "algorithms": ["br", "gz"],
    "filetypes": [
      ".html",
      ".js",
      ".css",
      ".svg",
      ".png",
      ".jpg",
      ".mp3",
      ".wav",
      ".tff",
      ".woff2"
    ],
    "directory": "/build"
  }
```

Create build and check

`npm run build`

`npx serve -s build`